# Suppress formatting/hyperlink tags in Matlab diary file?

Tags: matlab

If you capture the command window output using the diary function, table headings and row names are enclosed in <strong>...</strong> tags.  They're easy enought to remove using global search and replace, but if you generate the diary file frequently, it quickly becomes tiring.  Is there a way to suppress the tags in displaying tables?

I posted a similar question on [usenet](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/S02YtKDCfdQ) some time ago, though not in the context of tables.  The symptom is the same (tags in the otherwise text output diary file).

Note that the generalization of this question is how to get rid of tags in the output text in *general*.  For example, if you display an object of class 'myClass', there will be tags around the class name in the diary text.  The tags are much more complicated than the "strong" tags above, e.g., they specify help popups and style parameters.  But the question remains the same: Suppressing the content that clutters a text-only view.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vim script that removes formatting and hyperlink tags from a Matlab diary file.

```
" CleanMLdiary.vim
% s/<a href="[^>]\+>//g
% s=</a>==g
% s=^\[^H==g
% s=^H $
% s=<\\\?strong>==g
% s=</\?strong>==g
```

The `^H` is entered in insert mode using `<Ctrl-V><Ctrl-H>`.  The script can be run using `:source path/to/cleanMLdiary.vim`.

It can also be defined as a function in one's vimrc file:

```
function! CleanMLdiary()
   % s/<a href="[^>]\+>//g
   % s=</a>==g
   % s=^\[^H==g
   % s=^H $
   % s=<\\\?strong>==g
   % s=</\?strong>==g
endfunction
```

The function is invoked using `:call CleanMLdiary()`.